# Undefined reference when compiling C code

Tags: c

I'd like to compile a C program using SDL library on my Ubuntu.

I get this error from my compiler:

```
Undefined reference to `SDL_FreeSurface'.
```

As well as other undefined references.

Comment: You're missing [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php), probably (with gcc instead of g++). You should follow [the whole tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/), it's not bad resource for SDL2, although it uses C++. API doesn't change, though.

Comment: A "undefined reference" error is most likely due to you forgetting to pass a needed library to the linker.  You will probably need to pass not only the name of the library (*i.e.* -lSDL2) but also where the library is located (-L/usr/lib/sdl).  Note that the name of the library does not include the 'lib' prefix or the '.so.version' suffix; so if the library's name is 'libSDL2.so.1.3.4' you would only use  SDL2 for the name .  Finally, once your program compiles, it still may not run due to the loader not being able to find the required SDL library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like thurizas says, "Undefined reference" means that an external function or variable you use cannot be found by the linker (the part of the compiler which pieces together your code objects into the final program). Usually this means you forgot to link with a library, or your linker found the wrong version of that library.

In this case you should add "-lSDL2" to your compiler command line which means "link with libSDL2.so". This is necessary *in addition* to you #including the header files. Only the standard C library (libc.so) is linked in by default (-lc).

Comment: So should I change my "main.c" file? My include lines looks like this: 
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>#include <stdio.h>.  Will writing "-ISDL2" nearby do fine?

Comment: No. You must have the #include in your C file *in addition* to giving the -lSDL2 flag to the compiler. If you don't know how to pass flags to the compiler it may be time to google up how to do that.

Comment: Problem solved. I created makefile with -ISDL2.